# In the output of "aptitude update", what do "Ign" and the other codes mean?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, debian, aptitude

When I run `sudo aptitude update` from the console, I see output with lines such as this:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release.gpg [198B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Translation-en_GB
```

or this:

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Translation-en_GB
```

scrolling by.

It's fairly clear that `Get:N` indicates a download, `Hit` indicates when I've got something already, and that whatever `Ign` lines are, they can appear even if `source.list` has no comments, so they're not 'skipping comment' indicators as I've seen some people say.

After a fair amount of googling, though, that's as far as I've been able to get, so I have two questions:

1. What *exactly* does the `Ign` code indicate?
2. Is there any documentation (official or otherwise) that lists all the available codes along with what they're for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly does the Ign code indicate?

It means *Ignored*. That is, your local file is too recent to be refetched.

> Is there any documentation (official or otherwise) that lists all the available codes along with what they're for?

I don't know. I wouldn't be surprised if there was none, perhaps because it seems obvious, or because of laziness.

Comment: Can you explain "too recent to be refetched"?  That sounds (to me) like "The version I have is already the latest version," which I thought was what `Hit` meant.  Do you mean something like "That file's so recent that I won't even check whether or not it's up to date"?

Comment: @PaulWhittaker: yes to "That file's so recent that I won't even check whether or not it's up to date".

Comment: thanks.  So, has anyone else seen any documentation?

Comment: @PaulWhittaker: I have looked at the source, and there doesn't appear to be any.

Comment: I think answer from this link http://superuser.com/questions/454867/how-do-ign-and-hit-affect-apt-get-update has more information, and it said that you got Ign when "there was an error retrieving the file, but the error is being ignored."

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect. If you were to run 'apt-get update', and then again, you'd think ALL sources would show 'Ign' on the second update, because the local files would be up to date. But this is not the case.

Comment: I've noticed recently that I only see this when fetching the `InRelease` files on for repositories that already have separate `Release` and `Release.gpg` files.  I'm thus assuming that `Ign` means "harmlessly not present" or "logically irrelevant" rather than saying anything about my local system.  In particular, it can't mean "your local copy is too recent" in those cases, since there is no local file.

Comment: Tshepang: would you consider updating your answer in light of my and other comments above?  (I'd prefer not to de-accept it if that can be avoided.)  As it currently stands, I (now) consider the statement about local files being too recent to be incorrect, based on evidence I've seen, and agree instead with @HVNSweeting's comment.

Comment: @PaulWhittaker feel free to update it for me... I will be notified of the Edit

Comment: @PaulWhittaker I only checked the Edit now and found it rejected. I think you should just add an Answer.